# Python: Write csv header "with open"

Tags: python, csv, header

I have the following code where I generate a csv file without using csv module, and I was wondering what is the best way to do the header for this file:

```
for language in languages:
    with open ('user_edits.csv', 'a') as f: 
        f.write(str(user_count)+","+str(language[0])+","+str(language[1])+","+str(language[2])+"\n")
```

Comment: `",".join(str(x) for x in ([user_count] + language[:3]))` is better.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file only once and use csv module's functions:

```
import csv
with open ('user_edits.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    for language in languages:
       writer.writerow([user_count]+language[:3])
```

Comment: but how would i get the head lets say i want a,b,c,d as column headers?

Comment: @find-missing-semicolon Do you want to set the header or get the header?

Comment: @find-missing-semicolon Before the loop add this line: `writer.writerow(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])`